# Unsupported operands, finding an alternative to calculate values

Tags: python, calculation

I am trying to find the current `I` using an equation and values provided. However, I am getting the error `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'`. I have been reading through other questions similar to mine and know that Python does not allow calculations on lists. What I have not been able to figure out is how to carry out the calculation in a way that python allows. I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

The first portion of the code is working fine. I have left it in as the following equation needs the value of V that the first finds.

```
V = []
for t in np.arange(0, 10, 0.1):
     volt=(math.e**(-0.06*np.pi*t))*math.sin(2*t - np.pi)
     V.append(volt)
     print(volt, 'Volts')

R = 1.4
L = 1.7
C = 0.3
I = []

for t in np.arange(0.1, 10, 0.1):
    I = (C*(V/t**2)+(1/R)*(V/t)+(V/L))
    I.append(I)
    print(I, 'Amps', t, 'seconds')
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.plot(np.arange(0.1, 10, 0.1), I)
ax.set_title('Current as a function of time')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Current (I)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of lists, try using a numpy array (documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)).  This will allow you to do math operations on a collection of values at once, as you're trying to do with lists here.

To initialise `V` and `I`:

- If it's an array of known size, initialise it as an empty array first and then change each element in the for loop.
- If it's an array of unknown size, initialise it with size 0 and use the numpy `append` function to add elements to the array. Documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).